# Nodal Analysis and Matrices for more complex circuits

Tags: matrix, nodal-analysis

I would like to know how I should write a matrix equation for a circuit containing dependent sources, diodes, capacitors, and voltage sources.

I am familiar with the \$\small G V = I\$ matrix equation but is there a more general way for the elements I mentioned? For example:

[image]

How can find the node voltages of this circuit using methods like nodal inspection?

Comment: Provide a concrete example to better illustrate your question, please.

Comment: @jonk I did. thanks

Comment: You will need to select a ground reference in order to develop a matrix. Which node do you like?

Comment: Let's say the down right corner @jonk

Comment: There's really only two unknown node voltages. The other two are known, if you re-arrange the serial components in the branches properly. However, since you are looking for a general approach that doesn't use knowledge about serial 2-terminal device re-arrangements, does this mean you want a 4 element vector?

Comment: @jonk Yes, I saw that if all sources are independent-current- sources we can write a matrix $G$ now i want to see what to do if it's a general circuit with dependent components.

Comment: I think you need to re-draw the schematic with nodes identified, resistors given identifiers, and some thinking on your part about how to approach the question. I can add thoughts to that, once added. It's difficult to talk about what you are showing, right now. A SPICE program eliminates certain nodes from the vector if they are determined directly from other nodes by a constant value, for example.